# Why does this powershell command display all mailboxes instead of some?

Tags: azure, powershell, office365, azure-powershell

I have a list shared mailboxes in SharedMailboxes.csv that I would like to see their account status in Azure. However, when I run the following, I get a list of ALL users in Azure.

What am I missing?

```
Import-Csv C:\Temp\SharedMailboxes.csv | ForEach-Object {Get-AzureADUser -SearchString $_.SearchString | select UserPrincipalName,AccountEnabled}
```

Comment: I’d verify you’re CSV property names and output by itself first

Comment: I don't think it's possible to answer your question unless you show a few lines of the CSV file you're importing. (Is it really a CSV file, or just a plain text file?)

Comment: Sorry, I should have added the csv only has one column labeled "name", and it contains the mailbox names.

Comment: Then it should be `-SearchString $_.name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0), `-SearchString $_.name` is the code working good to fetch specific users.

I tried to repro the same issue and worked with the code `-SearchString $_.name`

1. Below command will help you in importing the users list to csv file from azure active directory

`Get-AzADUser -First 10 |  export-csv -Path "C:\Users\hari\source\repos\users.csv"`

[image: CSVExportUsers10]

2. After this, use the below command

`Import-Csv "C:\Users\hari\source\repos\users.csv" | ForEach-Object {Get-AzADUser -SearchString $_.Name | select UserPrincipalName,AccountEnabled}`

[image]

To get more information on `Get-AzADUser -SearchString` retrieve data commands, refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0)